# New type of notifications in Firefox - private_data

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/PopupNotifications.jsm

I want to create a new type of notifications "private_data-notification".

I copied the example of the part - https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/18500322/

I tried this:

```
const {Cc, you, Cu} = require (" chrome ");
let tmp = {};
Cu.import ("resource: //gre/modules/PopupNotifications.jsm" tmp);
var chromeWindow = require ("sdk / window / utils"). getMostRecentBrowserWindow ();
var pn = new tmp.PopupNotifications (
chromeWindow,
chromeWindow.document.getElementById ("notification-popup")
chromeWindow.document.getElementById ("notification-popup-box")
)
```

Return error: `Invalid tabbrowser`.

How to use it?

Comment: Try making the first rgument of `tm.PopupNotifications` to `chromeWindow.gBrowser`

Comment: Nice was that that solution? Adding in `gBrowser`?

Comment: Yes. Adding in gBrowser.

Comment: What do these popupnotifications look like can you share a screenshot? Are they like desktop notifications that don't go away till dismissed? Because I can use those :)

Comment: https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3206/popupnotification.png
https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3207/popupnotification.png

I also found how to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_popup_notifications

Comment: Ah very nice! I like to use notification bars: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/3926a0e9b51cebecf23c